# How do I add a bi-directionally bind the selection of a CheckBox with the selection of a row in a TableView?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to figure out how to bind a checkbox to it's row's selection model such that when the user selects one or more rows, the respective checkboxes are selected, and if the user selects one or more of the checkboxes, the respective rows are selected.

Ultimately, I need to be able to use the TableView.getSelectionModel() API to grab the selected items out of the table.

```
class PersonTable
        extends TableView<Person> {


    PersonTable() {

        this(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    }


    PersonTable(final ObservableList<Person> items) {

        super(items);

        setEditable(true);
        getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        final TableColumn<Person, CheckBox> selectedColumn = new TableColumn<>();
        selectedColumn.setCellFactory(param -> {
            final CheckBoxTableCell<Person, CheckBox> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
            cell.setSelectedStateCallback(index -> {
                final boolean selected = getSelectionModel().isSelected(index);
                return new SimpleBooleanProperty(selected);
            });
            return cell;
        });

        final TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            final Person person = param.getValue();
            final String name = person.getName();
            return new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        });

        final TableColumn<Person, String> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>("Age");
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            final Person person = param.getValue();
            final String age = person.getAge();
            return new SimpleStringProperty(age);
        });

        final TableColumn<Person, String> sexColumn = new TableColumn<>("Sex");
        sexColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            final Person person = param.getValue();
            final String sex = person.getSex();
            return new SimpleStringProperty(sex);
        });

        getColumns().add(selectedColumn);
        getColumns().add(nameColumn);
        getColumns().add(ageColumn);
        getColumns().add(sexColumn);
    }
}
```

The above displays the table, and each row gets a checkbox that can be checked and unchecked, but I can't seem to figure out how to bind the checkbox's selected value to the row's selected value.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @kleopatra I am trying to figure out how to get the checkbox bound to the row's selection model, such that if the row is selected, so is the checkbox and vice versa.

Comment: @kleopatra To explain further, I have an application with a TableView where the user can select one or more items to be edited. However, users do not understand how to select more than one item (via control + click or shift + click). So I have been exploring using checkboxes for that purpose instead.

Comment: @Cypher So why do you need it bound to selection? Can't you just let the user check the check boxes, and then perform whichever action you need on the rows with checked check boxes?

Comment: @James_D It's a common control (in a lib) that is used by lots of projects with the documented expectation that callers can use the SelectionModel of the TableView to get selected items. Unless I am mistaken, I think what you are proposing would not allow that any longer and would likely be rejected by other teams.